# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str...(Dominant_emotion)

Tags: python, dictionary, opencv, face-detection, deepface

im trying to print the dominant_emotion in live cam among 7 emotions after analysing from "deepface" in opencv. But im unable to print dominant emotion!

python code:

```
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    result = DeepFace.analyze(img_path=frame, actions=['emotion'], enforce_detection=False)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 3)

    #emotionz = result["dominant_emotion"]

    txt = str(result['dominant_emotion'])
    cv2.putText(frame, txt, (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    print(result)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error:

```
File "C:\Users\H\PycharmProjects\EmotionDet\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    txt = list(result['dominant_emotion'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Im able to print,normal result with all emotion..

Comment: `result` is a list. You can't index it with strings. `result[0]['dominant_emotion']` might work.

Answer (score 0):

I actually stumbled on this problem today when I ran a similar code in a newer machine. I didn't have this issue on the older machine, and I found that it worked because it was running an older version of the the deepface package.

If you installed deepface recently, you might be running version newer than 0.0.75. You can find the package version by opening command prompt (if on Windows, I don't know about how other OSes work) and inputting "py -m pip list".

If the version is newer that 0.0.75, you will have to uninstall deepface by inputting "py -m pip uninstall deepface", and then reinstall the older version by inputting "py -m pip install deepface==0.0.75".

Doing so has fixed the issue for me on the newer machine today. Hopefully it does so for you too.

I'm new to answering in Stack Overflow, so I apologize for not making this answer easier to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The new structure of deepface has the following list structue:

```
    print(result[0]["dominant_race"][:])
    print(result[0]["dominant_emotion"][:])
    print(result[0]["age"])
    print(result[0]["dominant_gender"][:])
```